# Common identifier for types of places

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a word or phrase for a type of place that is man made? e.g. haven, bastion, etc

Comment: Can you clarify - are you looking for a word that describes *all* man-made structures and locations?

Comment: What is the context where you would use this word?

Comment: @JHCL it would just be a word that all words that describe a manmade place would fall under

Comment: @Barmar it would be used as a noun e.g. "This was the last bastion of the resistance"

Comment: But all these words describe different types of places. What is the context where you would use this collective noun?

Comment: The most general word I can think of is "building", but there are many types of places that aren't buildings. Bastions and havens don't even describe the places, they're more conceptual, desribing the purposes.

Comment: So you're looking for a sinlge *collective* noun that describes 'all man-made structures' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well in this instance, what about [**Construct**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/construct):

> a product of ideology, history, or social circumstances (-- Merriam-Webster)

- "the last construct of the resistance"

I know it's usually applied to abstract concepts, but the 'construction' link, together with context, should help carry your meaning.

Comment: Yeah I think that this is fairly close to what I mean